# How to determine number of dynamic partitions in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase, apache-pig

I was executing an insert statement for a table that was partitioned and bucketed
but during the run, it threw an error about the number of dynamic partitions -- namely, that there were not enough.

So, I set as follows:

```
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=2000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=2000;
```

Can anyone explain what number of partitions these should be set to?  I just gave a random value to these.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?